# Status bar appears below UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

Status bar are always at the top of any uiview which we add as subview to main view of View controller. 
In my case I am getting it below view Header.

[image: Simulator screenshot which is same in Device]

My View Hierarchy is

[image: View Header is the subview where 'About Us' is written]

Is there anything to do with constraints? I have never seen such issue previously and can't find suitable solution please help !! Thanks.

Comment: apply a top margin of 20 to your main UIView . so the status bar appears to front... edit top constraint of the main view

Comment: I think thats not possible. The constraints are disabled for the same.